# GAE Channels to multiple clients?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, websocket

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `channel` features of Google App Engine since they don't (easily) provide websockets.

My current situation is that I have a long work (file processing) that is being executed asynchronously via a worker.
This worker update the state of the file processing in the database at every lines in order to inform the customer.

From that current perspective, a F5 will indicate the evolution of the processing.

Now I'd like to implement a live update system. Of course I could do an XHR request every 5 seconds but a live connection seems better... introducing Channels since Websockets seems out of the possibilities.

From what I understood, I can `channel.send_message` to one client only, not to a "room". The issue here, is that the worker that process the file does not have any information which customer is currently connected (could be one, could be ten).

I could loop over all the customer and post to each client_id, suspecting that at least one of them will get the message, but this is awfully useless and too resourceful.

I was hoping there was a better way to achieve this ? Maybe a nice alternative to Google `Channels` feature without having to reconfigure my whole App Engine system (like for Websockets)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of, which is not the absolute ideal but would be more suited, is to manage dedicated database tables (could also be implemented in Memcache) with :

- A table that contains a list of rooms
- A table that contains a list of `client_id` connected to the room

e.g. :

- Rooms (id, name)
- Clients (id, room_id, client_id)

Now, instead of posting to `channel.send_message(client_id, Message)`, one would make a wrapper like this :

```
def send_to_room(room, message):
    # Queries are SQLAlchemy like :

    room = Rooms.query.filter(Rooms.name === room).first()
    if not room:
        raise Something

    clients = Clients.query.filter(Rooms.room_id === room.id).all()
    for client in clients:
        channel.send_message(client.client_id, message)
```

And voilà, you have a Room like implementation in Google App Engine.

The drawback of this solution is to add two tables (or equivalent) in your database.

Does someone has better?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the long running task is being kicked off by the client.
So before you kick off the task make a ajax request from the client to a handler similar to this one. This handler has two things returned to the client. The token param which is used by the javascript api to create a channel, and a cid param which is used to determine which client created the channel.

```
    from google.appengine.api import channel
    @ae.route("/channel")
    class CreateChannel(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            cid = str(uuid.uuid4())
            token = channel.create_channel(cid)
            data = {
                "cid":cid,
                "token":token
            }
            self.response.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Now use the channel javascript api to create a new channel
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript

```
    var onClosed = function(resp){
      console.log("channel closed");
    };
    var onOpened = function(resp){
      console.log("channel created");
    };
    var onmessage = function(resp){
        console.log("The client received a message from the backend task");
        console.log(resp);
    };
    var channel_promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/channel",
    method: "GET"
    });
    channel_promise.then(function(resp){
    //this channel id is important you need to get it to the backend process so it knows which client to send the message to.
    var client_id = resp.data.cid;
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(resp.data.token);
        handler = {
            'onopen': $scope.onOpened,
            'onmessage': $scope.onMessage,
            'onerror': function () {
            },
            'onclose': function () {
                alert("channel closed.")
            }
        };
        socket = channel.open(handler);
        //onOpened is the callback function to call after channel has been created
        socket.onopen = onOpened;
        //onClose is the callback function to call after channel has been        closed
        socket.onclose = onClosed;
        //onmessage is the callback function to call when receiving messages from your task queue
        socket.onmessage = onMessage;
        });
```

Now we are all set up to listen for channel messages. 
So when the user clicks the button we need to kickoff the backend task.

```
    var letsDoSomeWorkOnClick = function(){
         //make sure you pass the client id with every ajax request
         $.ajax({
             url: "/kickoff",
             method: "POST",
             params: {"cid":client_id} 
         });
    }
```

Now the app engine handler to start the backend task queue. I use the deffered library to do this. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

```
   @ae.route("/kickoff")
   KickOffHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       def post(self):
           cid = self.request.get("cid")
           req = {}
           req['cid'] = cid
           task = MyLongRunningTask()
           deferred.defer(task.long_runner_1, req, _queue="my-queue")
```

example task:

```
    class MyLongRunningTask:

          def long_runner_1(self,req):
               # do a whole bunch of stuff
               channel.send_message(req["cid"], json.dumps({"test":"letting client know task is done"})
```

Comment: I'm sorry I believe you misunderstood my question. The issue here was how can I send the same message to many clients connected to the application ("Room" like for Websockets), since Google doesn't allow this.

Comment: Oh yes I did, I thought you wanted to send a message to specific client. My mistake.

Comment: I feel embarrassed because you wrote a comprehensive a complete answer :/

Comment: No problem it was my fault for not reading your question throughly. Did you happen to check out the "Tracking client connections and disconnections" section in the channel api ?                                                                          [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/)

Comment: If you can track which clients are connected/disconnected to a specific channel you should be able to post a message to all the clients in the "Room"

Comment: I did it with the solution I posted below. With a datastore that keeps track of who's connected, and sends the message to all those persons.